ASP.NET Core app cannot find the SQL Server in Docker-Compose
This is my appsettings.Production.json file, I am using a different port number than the default.
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=docker-demo-sqlserver,1432;Database=DockerComposeDemo;User=sa;Password={0};TrustServerCertificate=True"
  }
}

And this is my docker-compose file
version: '3.8'

services:
  docker-demo-web-api:
    container_name: docker-demo-web-api-container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerDemoWebApi/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password1*
    ports:
      - "5000:8080"
    depends_on:
      - docker-demo-sqlserver    
  docker-demo-sqlserver:
    container_name: docker-demo-sqlserver-container
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password1*
    ports:
      - "1432:1432"

Although I use the same port number in the docker-compose file The app cannot find the docker-demo-sql server service.
docker-demo-web-api-container    | Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
docker-demo-web-api-container    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
docker-demo-web-api-container    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
docker-demo-web-api-container    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean withFailover)  
docker-demo-web-api-container    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) 
docker-demo-web-api-container    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
docker-demo-web-api-container    |    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)

When I change the port number to 1433 in the connection string, it works well even I don't change the docker-compose port number(1432:1432).
I don't understand, it seems the app or SQL service doesn't care the port number in the docker-compose file. Only When I change the port number 1433 to 1432 in the connection string it gives errors.

The ports section in the docker-compose.yml files is equivalent to the -p (publish) parameter in docker run commands, i.e.: it only affects ports published on the Docker host, not which ports are exposed among the Docker containers. Since the mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server containers only listen on port 1433, and only expose port 1433, you can have other containers within the composition connect even if there are no ports published on the host at all.
